# WinDbg: How do I programmatically parse output from `dt`?

Tags: arrays, windbg

The WinDbg `dt` command is very useful for displaying type information, and I commonly use `dt -a <memory-address> <type>` to output type information for an array of elements.

How do I programmatically manipulate the values output by `dt`?  Specifically, for each element in the array, I'd like to output the bit shifted value of each element in the array (`??(array-element)>>1` for each value in the array).  I've tried this for an array of 100 elements (with an example array memory address of 0xDEADBEEF, with datatype MY_TYPE):

```
.for (r $t0=0; @$t0<0n100; r $t0=@$t0+1) { ??(dt 0xDEADBEEF)+(@@c++(sizeof(MY_TYPE))*@$t0) MY_TYPE)>>1 }
```

Essentially, for each element in the array, I'd like to print the output of `dt`, with the numerical value shifted by 1.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use pykd. It give you python API for debug angine of the windbg. You can work with typed variable in two way:

1. Simple way: parsing.

   dtoutput = pykd.dbgCommand("dt _MYTYPE address")

   callDtParser(dtoutput)  # parse text as you can: re ....
2. Right way:  pykd.typedVar

   myvar = pykd.typedVar("_MYTYPE", address )

   print myvar.arrayField[10] >> 2 # compare with C

How to install pykd ( with bootstarpper )
https://pykd.codeplex.com/releases/view/614442

Tip: don't use python 2.7.11 - it has a bug and does not work in embedding application ( you can fix it by changing default python registartion )

Comment: Thank you.  I think this will work.  I also found another solution, which I posted as a reference.

Comment: windbg scripting is cool, but it takes much time, I spent a lot of hours on it :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `qwo`, as it reads from memory:

```
.for (r $t0=0; @$t0<0n100; r $t0=@$t0+1) { r @$t1 = qwo(DEADBEEF+(@$t0*@@c++(sizeof(MY_TYPE))));?@$t1>>1 }
```

Since `qwo` is a memory-reading function, the value can be manipulated programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

NatVis is now the solution for this type of problem:

https://www.osr.com/blog/2015/11/06/fun-windbg-natvis-support/

Basically you use XML to describe how you want the structure displayed and then display it using dx instead of dt.